# Add link to Shopping Cart on Woocommerce's Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, woocommerce

I've seen many tutorials dealing on how to customize woocommerce's checkout page by adding or removing fields.

But what I want is to place a link or button on the Woocommerce Checkout page saying "Return to Cart" (obviously linking to the cart page) but I want it placed just after the "Your Order" section, (the section where you review your order). I want it there because I want it along with a text saying something like "If you want to change your order *return to Cart*".

If I edit the actual checkout page and add the link there, it shows all the way to the bottom so maybe I have to add code to the theme's functions file? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: 
Ok, I've found a very crappy way of doing it.
I just added this line to the review-order.php file located in woocommerce/templates/checkout/ , right after the shop_table class:

```
<?php echo "<strong>If you'd like to change your order, go back to <a href='http://www.mysite.com/cart/'>My Cart</a></strong><br />"; ?>
```

This does the trick, but everytime I update woocommerce I will have to added it again.
Any suggestion of a more practical and intelligent way of doing it?

Comment: You'll have to show us some example code.

Answer (score 5):

[Create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Creating_a_Child_Theme_from_an_Unmodified_Parent_Theme).

Put this in the child theme's functions.php

```
/**
*   Add link back to cart after order review on Checkout
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'my_back_to_cart_link' );
function my_back_to_cart_link(){
    //get the cart link
    global $woocommerce;
    $cartUrl = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
    //the HTML markup to add
    $backToCartLink="<p class='backtocart'><a class='button alt' href='".$cartUrl."'>".__('Edit Cart','wooint')."</a></p>";
    echo $backToCartLink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you created a child theme you could have put that line in your child's functions.php and then the only way an update would affect it is if they changed the coding.